# MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a simple question, I google'd it but my english isn't that good so.

I have 2 tables with both the structure row ID

both are auto_increment but I want them to be in sync so basically both always have to have the same ID number is that possible?

Comment: you should keep the other table referred to previous table by `foreign key`

Comment: In a RDBMS, it is not necessary that the id for both tables are sync, you have to use `FOREIGN KEY` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but it would be better to have one column that is connected to the other table ID

table1:

```
ID
```

table2:

```
ID
table1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use that auto increment field as primary key in one table. and refer the same field as foreign key in another table.

but auto increment depends on how you are going to insert records in both table.

```
Table1 :  
ID  -primary key

Table2 :
tablei-id  -foriegn key
```